# How to Access Google Docs in an Ios App?

Tags: ios, ios5, google-docs

Hello i want to access the google docs in my app.Can any one help me. I have used the google data client library but it is for mac OS. I want it for ios .Please help

Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to just port the code over to iOS. You can compile google-api-objectivec-client for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/) supports the Google Drive API and is the recommended library to access your documents in iOS and Mac OS X applications.

The library also includes a complete sample for Google Drive:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FExamples%2FDriveSample

Comment: Hello thanks for reply but these API is for MAC OS and while building for iOS platform it shows the error 'Cocoa/Cocoa.h' file not found. Please suggest if it can be done in ioS sdk also.